# SPSS : Writing the result of calcul into a csv file

Tags: csv, timer, dataset, spss

i specify here that i'm a true newbie at SPSS, i just started since 3hours for a student projet.

So, what i want to do is open a file, and do some statistics test on it, then measure the times it takes to SPSS to do so and finally writing into a file.

So for that i'm writing first into a new dataset, and then i will write this one into a file. This is my code for now :

```
    DATASET NAME Set1 WINDOW=FRONT.

compute temps_mean_deb=$TIME.
mean v1 to v128.
COMPUTE temps_mean_fin=$TIME.

COMPUTE temps_mean= temps_mean_fin - temps_mean_deb.

COMPUTE temps_median_deb=$TIME.
EXAMINE v1 to v128 
/PLOT NONE
/PERCENTILES(50). 
COMPUTE temps_median_fin=$TIME.

COMPUTE temps_median = temps_median_fin - temps_median_deb.
list temps_mean  temps_median.
DATA LIST free /datatype (A10) kind (A10) tailleMatrice (A10) distrib (A10) drange (A10) reroll (A10) operation (A10) duree (A10)   implementation (A10).
BEGIN DATA
integ thin 1 unif bina 1 mean temps_mean SPSS
integ thin 1 unif bina 1 median temps_median SPSS
end data.
```

what i want it's write the variable "temps_mean" and "temps_median" into a new data list. 
The problem is SPSS is just writing "temps_median"/ "temps_mean" but not the result of this calcul : `COMPUTE temps_median = temps_median_fin - temps_median_deb.`

And the result is obviously what i want 
So thanks for your help !

Comment: Please explain what the problem is - did you get an error message? on what line did the error occur? what were you expecting and what actually happened? (in any case some of your commands do not have a `.` at the end, which could cause some problems)

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a `DATA LIST` command with `BEGIN DATA` and `END DATA` to read in data, the data is between those two lines. You're reading in the strings "temps_mean" and "temps_median" as the data. There's no reference there to an existing variable anywhere in the SPSS system.

You would need to put the numbers desired in those input lines in order to get them in as data with the other strings you've included. For something with just these two values, copying and pasting them from the Data Editor cells or the output of the `LIST` command would seem simplest.